# Drupal: what do these permissions expose me to

Tags: drupal, permissions

I needed to give these permissions to anonimous and authenticated user:

- Content: Bypass content access control
- Views: Bypass views access control

(otherwise these users could not see content of a view)

Is there something I need to protect anywhere else? is it a "dangerous" practice or it's whithin excepted permissions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's very dangerous practice, that's why you get a nice big warning right underneath those permissions on the main permissions page:

> *Warning: Give to trusted roles only; this permission has security implications.*

It means that any visitor to your site can add/edit/remove any content and views that they wish. If that suits your use case (although I can't imagine it would) then giving these permissions to everyone is the correct thing to do.

If not, I suggest you define a proper security policy and look at modules like [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) to secure your site.

Comment: That's what I was doing but there's no way these users can see this view content if I don't give these permissions, I'm not happy about that. Is there any way to avoid content editing even with these permissions given? (I tested that module and I only found it adds 2 permissions, to avoid other users aquiring unwanted permissions but I don't see how it can help me), thank you

Comment: There's no way to override that permission really. If you grant it to a role, anyone with that role will be able to add/edit any content on the site. That's what that particular permission is actually for. I'm not sure why you can't just grant 'access content' to the roles in question though, that will let anyone view content but only admins delete it

Comment: I don't know why it happens but I wasn't able to solve this other way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185194/drupal-view-shows-only-one-row (the view has unrestricted access)